# XML parsing: Loop through a child node and save field,values to a hash map

Tags: java, xml, loops, parsing, nodes

I have an XML with the following structure.

```
<message>
  <header>

  </header>

  <body> 

  </body>

  <end> 

  </end>
</message>
```

Each header,body and end nodes contain fields that i need to extract into separate hash maps. What is the best way to go about this without using external libraries? The end result is to display a two-column view of the entire message. (field name, value)

Comment: You can use jaxb to bind it to a pojo (i think you would have to implement a `javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter` and pass it in using `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation) or use `javax.xml.xpath.Xpath`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DocumentBuilderFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html) and [DocumentBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html) that comes along with java Api.
For Example, refer [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the structure of your data and your hashmap: what is the key, what if the value.

Nevertheless, DOM and XPATH do the job:

```
String xml= // your xml
DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory =DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
String expression="//header"; // Same for body, ...
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(expression) ; 
    NodeList nodes  = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int k = 0; k < nodes.getLength(); k++) {
// Do what you want with that
```

hope it helps